# openvpn: no internet when connected

Tags: openvpn

I've been trying to set up an openvpn connection between my laptop at home running ubuntu 16.04 and a dd-wrt router at my office. The issue is that I lose internet access when connected. Is important to note that I want all the traffic going through the vpn, including internet.
The dd-wrt router has this configuration for openvpn:

```
dh /tmp/openvpn/dh.pem
ca /tmp/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /tmp/openvpn/cert.pem
key /tmp/openvpn/key.pem
keepalive 10 120
verb 4
#mute 3
log-append /var/log/openvpn
writepid /var/run/openvpnd.pid
management 127.0.0.1 14
management-log-cache 50
topology subnet
client-config-dir /tmp/openvpn/ccd
script-security 2
port 1194
proto tcp-server
cipher aes-128-cbc
auth sha1
comp-lzo yes
tls-server
ifconfig-pool-persist /tmp/openvpn/ip-pool 86400
client-to-client
push "redirect-gateway def1"
tcp-nodelay
tun-mtu 1500
mtu-disc yes
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
dev tun2
tun-ipv6
route 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

The client script is the following:

```
remote [remote ip] 1194

client
remote-cert-tls server 
dev tun1
proto tcp
resolv-retry infinite 
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun 
ns-cert-type server
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo 
redirect-gateway
ca ca.crt 
cert awswin.crt 
key awswin.key
```

When I connect with this scripts the connection is established and when I look at openvpnlogs on the remote router it has logs about dropping packages because of "wrong source ip [my private non vpn ip]", this changes when I add a file named awswin (myclientname) on /tmp/openvpn/ccd/ containing "iroute 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0". Then the router stops dropping packages and changes the logs to "learn". But there is no internet.

Comment: You set your VPN network to `10.8.0.0/24`.  You are going to need to add firewall rules and possibly setup NAT on your vpn server to permit that network.  Assigning addresses to the VPN clients that aren't valid for the VPN network isn't going to do anything useful.

Comment: I did that too. iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

Comment: You probably need to look at your routing tables, and look at a traceroute from your client to something on the Internet.

Comment: I did that too.

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT

Comment: I was writing you a response attaching all the info an suddenly realized that my router does not have eth0 interface, changed iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE for eth+ and it worked!!! Thank you anyway, you made me realize my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve the issue. Actually it was documented everywhere but a little difference needed to be made for my router.
To make your router NAT through VPN you must add this rule to iptables:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
The thing is that my router was using eth1 as the interface, so it didn't work.
You can use eth+ instead of a number if you don't know the number of the interface, "+" works for any number.
Of course this example works when you use 10.8.0.0/24 as your vpn network (default).